# Simple program stops after 90 minutes or so

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a very simple program which runs a script every 2 seconds and places the output into a menu bar item. However, after around 90 minutes the menu bar item stops updating. Can anyone see why?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [_window setIsVisible:NO];
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess };
    TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToUIElementApplication);
    //the above code stops the dock icon from appearing (and also stops the application from appearing in the alt tab menu

    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"0%"]; 
    [statusItem setEnabled:YES];
    [statusItem setToolTip:@"Script output"];

    //[statusItem setAction:@selector(updateIPAddress:)];
    [statusItem setTarget:self];

    //NSString *output = [self unixSinglePathCommandWithReturn:@"/usr/bin/osascript \"/Users/Velox/Projects/Geektool Scripts/WorkDay.scpt\""];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(calcPercent) toTarget:[self class] withObject:nil];
}

+(void)calcPercent{
    while(true){
        NSString *output = [self unixSinglePathCommandWithReturn:@"/usr/bin/osascript \"/Users/Velox/Projects/Geektool Scripts/WorkDay.scpt\""];
        [statusItem setTitle:output];
        [statusItem setEnabled:YES];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    }
}

+ (NSString *)unixSinglePathCommandWithReturn:(NSString *) command {

    NSPipe *newPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [newPipe fileHandleForReading];
    NSData *inData = nil;
    NSString* returnValue = nil;

    NSTask *unixTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    unixTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [unixTask setStandardOutput:newPipe];
    [unixTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/csh"];
    [unixTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", command , nil]]; 
    [unixTask launch];
    [unixTask waitUntilExit];
    //int status = [unixTask terminationStatus];

    while ((inData = [readHandle availableData]) && [inData length]) {

        returnValue= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inData encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

        returnValue = [returnValue substringToIndex:[returnValue length]-1];

    }

    return returnValue;

}
```

I am using ARC.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments to profile the app? Perhaps there are memory leaks.

Comment: To quit it I am just killing it using Activity Monitor. The memory usage is higher than expected (around 30MB), but is it really enough to cause the app to grind to a halt? Either way, I am running the profiler just now checking for leaks.

Comment: After 4 and a half hours without it stopping, it finally did. But there were no more allocations that normal and no memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're using ARC (which is a wonderful thing, overall) does not mean you have to stop thinking about memory use and performance.

In your "`calcPercent`" method, you're repeatedly calling "`unixSinglePathCommandWithReturn:`".  When you get returnValue assigned and set and break out of your "`while`" loop, you should do "`unixTask = nil;`" which would encourage ARC to properly release the unix task object.

Another thing, you're calling it every two seconds.  Polling is extremely wasteful, so you should try to come up with a better way to do what you are trying to do.  For example, instead of every two seconds (while multiple other calls to that function might be stuck or hung or whatever), why not schedule the thing to run 2 seconds *after the conclusion* of the previous call to "`unixSinglePathCommandWithReturn`"?

b.t.w., you're double allocating "`unixTask"` (with two separate calls to "`[NSTask alloc] init]`) one after another.  If this were non-ARC code, that would be a big memory leak.  As it is right now, it just looks bad.

Comment: ARC handles both of the memory "issues" you pointed out correctly; neither of those cases will leak.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote @BJHomer. Maybe you're right about ARC handling the double "`alloc`" & "`init`" things (I'm not super familiar with ARC yet), but in a non-ARC environment it'd absolutely be a leak and it still looks super bad even with ARC turned on. We don't know what @Velox's script is doing, so it may be executing some massive CPU-intensive thing that takes more than 2 seconds to run, meaning multiple calls to "`unixSinglePathCommandWithReturn`" are piling up, so my suggestion to back off on the heavy polling (and preferably do something *else*) should still apply.

Comment: Sure. If you take out the suggestion that setting to nil would somehow help ARC, I'll remove the downvote. The advice on polling us good.

Comment: Oh dear... I accidentally removed the unixTask = nil line from my submission. It is there in my actual code. So that's not the issue. As for polling, it gets the results and returns them, then sleeps for 2 seconds. So it does only run 2 seconds after the end of the last one. However I agree that polling should be avoided if possible.